# How to erase a vector containing structs with std:unique_ptr?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

The next source code does not even compile unless the clear() vector line is commented. Is anyone able to explain me why and how to fix it?

```
#include <vector>

class Class
{
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<int> Variable;

public:
    Class() {}
    Class(Class&& other) { variables = std::move(other.variables); }

private:
    std::vector<Variable> variables;
};

void main()
{
    std::vector<Class> container;
    container.push_back(Class());
    container.clear();
}
```

I must remark that it has been tried in MS Visual Studio 2010 compiler (it could be said that it is a half c++11 implementation). Sadly I have not found any online compiler that allows to use VS 2010.

Anyway, the error report is next:

```
1>------ Operación Generar iniciada: proyecto: Binary, configuración: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compilación iniciada a las 30/05/2018 13:28:52.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Aplicando tarea Touch a "Debug\Binary.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2156): error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::operator =' : no se puede obtener acceso al miembro private miembro declarado en la clase 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(2352) : vea la declaración de 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2177) : vea la referencia a la creación de instancias de plantilla de función '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' que se está compilando
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::unique_ptr<int> *,
1>              _InIt=std::unique_ptr<int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(719) : vea la referencia a la creación de instancias de plantilla de función '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<std::unique_ptr<_Ty>*,std::unique_ptr<_Ty>*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' que se está compilando
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::unique_ptr<int> *,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _InIt=std::unique_ptr<int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(709) : durante la compilación de la función miembro de plantilla de clase 'std::vector<_Ty> &std::vector<_Ty>::operator =(const std::vector<_Ty> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Class::Variable
1>          ]
1>          c:\vc\protocolreader\main.cpp(13) : vea la referencia a la creación de instancias de plantilla de clase 'std::vector<_Ty>' que se está compilando
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Class::Variable
1>          ]
1>
1>ERROR al compilar.
1>
1>Tiempo transcurrido 00:00:01.09
========== Generar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
```

Please, you may use an online service to translate it to english from spanish if you need.

Comment: "does not even compile" -> please add the compiler error message

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is compiling without commenting clear line http://cpp.sh/3bmwr

Comment: I can't help but notice that in your sample the destructor is missing. When you call clear, the destructor of the object will be called. Maybe it's related ?

Comment: @Clonk the destructor is implicitly defined

Comment: @Caleth Yeah you're right. I'm just not used to have a move constructor without following the rules of five that it didn't felt natural to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the move assignment for `Class`:

```
Class& operator=(Class&& other)
{
    variables = std::move(other.variables);
    return *this;
}
```

The code does not compile, because the copy assignment operator of `Class` is not available, since it contains a non-copyable member. Modern compilers would use a default generated move assignment operator instead, however, Visual Studio 2010 does not do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was going in that way already but finally you have done things easier. I guess it is the price to pay if you are given stone age tools by project requests.